# Schedule reminders by the tag info

Tags: tags

We're using the tab 'tags' to clasify certain members that belong to a specific working group.

Is it possible to schedule a reminder by the type of tag?

Thank you in advance for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can create group with contacts who has tag and restrict recipients in reminders based on group.